# How do I confirm that my address is attached to my wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I have created my wallet and have monero running in background, though I am not entirely sure how to tell.  I just know that I try to run ./monerod I receive an error message stating that "Address already in use".  Sine I am new to this I am worried that my wallet is not attached to my address.  If it is not, am I even accomplishing anything by running ./monerod?  I am sorry to keep posting but I had never used Linux until yesterday so large learning curve.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: "Address already in use" refers to the port you're binding to on your computer. Nothing to do with Monero addresses. The daemon also does not have access to your address or keys.

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a guess you are trying to run more than one monerod instance at a time. You can do this if you assign them different ports, otherwise you'll get that address already in use error. You only need one monerod instance running at a time.

With monerod running, open monero-wallet-cli. It will ask you for your wallet file location and the password. Once provided type the command `address` and it will display the address associated with that wallet.

Comment: Note that opening `monero-wallet-cli` from the location of your wallet may be the easiest.  Though there are several ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 2):

To see what address your wallet has, run this in monero-wallet-cli:

`address`

Similarly, you can run:

`viewkey`
`spendkey`

to get the keys.

`seed`

will get you the mnemonic seed.